# How to communicate between Node.JS processes in 2019

Tags: node.js, ipc

It's 2019 year and for last 5 years we used `zeromq.js` for communicating between our processes in cluster (to be more specific: we have different child processes, one of them is metrics and it needs to ask all other processes including master about new metrics etc).
We are using it because it isn't over http (no overhead, we are doing ~1000 requests/s) and can use unix socket domain - that means that we don't need port numbers, but instead we can use `/tcp/${process.env.uname}.sock` or something like this. It's good because there can be about 30 different processes and we want it to be zero-config.
But 4.6.0 was last stable version, we may found some memory leaks and other problems, but nobody accepts pull requests and check issues.

I was trying to use other libraries like node `axon` and `node-ipc` but they are also old and does not have support.
I was thinking of `cote` but we don't want to communicate between servers and Gossip protocol is blocked on our production servers.

Comment: Not much changed, we use rabbitmq.